# setMaximized() in JavaFX doesn't work properly

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

When running my javafx application I use setMaximized(true) to maximize the primary stage as follows:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/log_in.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("My Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This works perfectly when launching my application. However, I try to follow the same steps when changing the screen but am unable to obtain the same results. The following is my switch screen method:

```
void changeScreen(ActionEvent event, String fxmlFile) throws Exception {
    Parent newPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    Scene newScene = new Scene(newPage);
    Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    appStage.setScene(newScene);
    appStage.setMaximized(true);
    System.out.println(appStage.isMaximized());
    appStage.show();
}
```

The result of this method is changing from a maximized window to a smaller one and I am unsure as to why this is happening. As shown in my changeScreen() method I added a println statement to check if setMaximized() was working and the printed value is indeed true. However, the stage is not shown on my entire screen. How can I go about successfully switching screens and maintaining the screen maximized?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but have you tried invoking `setMaximized(true)` after invoking `show()` on the `Stage`?

Comment: Do you really need to change the scene here? I suspect that's what's causing the problem; it seems like the stage should already be maximized since you are using the same stage you maximized earlier. Why not just replace the root of the scene?

Comment: d.j.brown Just tried it and the problem still persists.

Comment: @James_D So I tried making a global static variable that represents the primary stage (in order to not create a new one). Afterwards I used that value to instead of creating the "app stage" variable I had created. However, I keep getting the same issue. Please correct me if this is not what you meant with your response.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant at all. You are already using the same stage, there is no need for an ugly hack like a public static variable for that. I meant, reuse the ***scene***, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you set the scene of the stage, the stage resizes to the size of the scene; since it's probably already maximized (since you're using the same stage you maximized earlier), my guess is that you are confusing the stage as to its state (this would be a bug).

However, I really don't see any point in creating a new scene here at all; that just seems like unnecessary overhead. Why don't you just reuse the same scene and replace the root?

```
void changeScreen(ActionEvent event, String fxmlFile) throws Exception {
    Parent newPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().setRoot(newPage);
}
```

If you are concerned that the user may have "unmaximized" the stage and want to ensure it is maximized after changing the view, you should be able to do that too:

```
void changeScreen(ActionEvent event, String fxmlFile) throws Exception {
    Parent newPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    Scene scene = ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
    scene.setRoot(newPage);
    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).setMaximized(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand what you mean now. What you are essentially doing is setting up a new root node (i.e. newPage) and replacing that node with the original one (i.e. root).